# Radio Buttons Set checked state through code

Tags: android, radio-button

I have three Radio buttons to specify the gender, Male Female and Others. I save this data into my DB as 1 for Male, 2 for female and three for others based on user selection. This is reflected in the profile page, now when I want to edit the profile I want to auto-populate all the fields of my profile page in an editable manner, the user only changes the fields he wants to. Although I am able to fetch the values of 1,2,3 for gender from my database but I am not able to populate the specified radio button as checked. I tried the following:

```
String M = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Gender")));
RadioGroup rb1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);

if(M.equals(1)){
    rb1.check(R.id.radiobutton3);
    RadioButton rbu1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton3);
    rbu1.setChecked(true);
}
else if(M.equals(2)){
    rb1.check(R.id.radiobutton4);
    RadioButton rbu2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton4);
    rbu2.setChecked(true);
}
else if(M.equals(3)){
    rb1.check(R.id.radiobutton5);
    RadioButton rbu3 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton5);
    rbu3.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: radiobutton.setSelected(true);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use either `radioButton.setChecked(true)`; or `radiobutton.setSelected(true)`;

Don't give rb1, here in your code rb1 refers to RadioGroup, set names for radio buttons.

```
String M = "3";
RadioGroup rb1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
RadioButton rbu1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
RadioButton rbu2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
RadioButton rbu3 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);

if(M.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
{
    rbu1.setChecked(true);
}
else if(M.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){

    rbu2.setChecked(true);
}
else if(M.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
{    
    rbu3.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Not working with radioButton.setChecked(true) nor with radiobutton.setSelected(true)

Comment: I am able to display the values fetched from the DB though, through the aid of a toast message!

Comment: in your code remove the following line  rb1.check(R.id.radiobutton3);

Comment: Removed! And then checked at the first place itself! Not working!

Comment: try this M.equalsIgnoreCase("2")

Comment: Yes Now it works, Thanks for the help!! I was retrieving string values and checking them as int!

Answer (score 2):

This is for set checked.

```
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```

This is for getting value of checked radiobutton

```
RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id)
{
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)rg.findViewById(id);

boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();

if (isChecked)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
           checkedRadioButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}});
```

Comment: I am fetching the checked state from The database mate!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
radioButton.setChecked(true);

radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
sex = rb.getText().toString().trim();
```